# Why is it ill advised to use pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request?

Tags: python, pyramid

My assumption is that the correct request object is not the guaranteed result, but I would like to know exactly why it's ill advised, and the recommended way is to pass the request object down the pipeline from a view function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the request object has gotten to the view it's recommended that you do not pass "as-is" to any non-web-specific code. Any code dealing with databases, etc shouldn't be coupled to pyramid's concept of a request. This pattern is easier to follow in Pyramid as it avoids a global request object.

The request object encompasses everything about why your view is being invoked, and making more code than necessary coupled to that object will cause you to write functions further down the pipeline that perhaps do "too much".

Comment: There are certain parts of my model code that sends out emails to users. Because I'm using pyramid_mailer, I need a request object to use it. I've written a helper function that calles get_current_request and uses that to send emails with pyramid_mailer to avoid having to pass the request object to my model code and then to the mailer. This keeps my model code decoupled from Pyramid. Is something like this ill-advised, and why exactly?

Comment: It's ill-advised from a design perspective because arguably "sending email" is not an operation that belongs in your model. On top of that, it may not be clear that your model code has the side-effect of sending email as there is no variables you can trace to see that dependency.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon. I don't send emails from my models, but I do send emails from code not directly within view code -- Such as auth functions that send invitations, reset passwords, etc. These functions are called in different parts of my code -- mainly from form callback functions. The true question I'm asking is whether there is a technical reason to avoid get_current_request, or whether this is simply a (strong) suggestion?

Comment: To make it clear, I'm not using the request object for any other reason besides the fact that it is required by certain functions, such as `pyramid_mailer.get_mailer`. I get what you're saying in that if I needed certain environment variables, I should just pass the request object as needed -- this is not the case. Is it still ill-advised?

Comment: It's never a good idea to depend on globals because it makes it difficult for anyone other than you to understand that code. It'd be better to get the mailer in your view and pass it into some code that may need it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what Michael Merickel is saying, but I have a lot of legacy Pylons apps that have been ported , and have needed to access the request object in a lot of various code.

To make that happen, virtually all of my functions that are 'web oriented' expect the request as their first argument.   I say virtually all, because some don't.  Its not because I didn't want them to, it's because I haven't ported them over to this paradigm yet.   There are a handful of modules that are not coupled to the web, and are named and constructed otherwise.  [ Stuff like text processing , etc , which are used by non-pyramid based apps for my project ]  But anything that could possibly act-on or interact-with the request -- it has the request as the first arg *whether or not i currently need it*.

The reason why my code isn't standard, is that I didn't listen to people like Michael and I still used get_current_request... until I started to run into problems and understood what they warned me about -- so I've been fixing stuff piecemeal as i can.

The two main factors that concerned me to stay away from using get_current_request() were:

1. when i want the request passed in: unit testing.  I came from Pylons where we had the global `g` and `c` objects.  I really loved their convenience.  Then I tried to write unit tests, and it was a total nightmare.  you constantly had to rewrite code to jam a request object in there.
2. when i want the request out: not everything is coupled to the web.  on a certain project, I have several daemons running periodic work via the Twisted framework.  they process a lot of the same data and share some tasks.  i also have migration scripts, crontabs, etc.  if anything in these required interaction with Pyramid, I'd have to maintain the same functions in duplicate projects.

so my approach has been to create one section of my lib that is tightly coupled to pyramid and requires a request object, and another section of my lib that is completely agnostic to pyramid.

My pyramid request object has a lot of useful stuff in it -- the headers, sessions, db connections, etc.  It's a very convenient place to stash 'request' oriented data.   Whenever there is a task that could likely be used by non-pyramid systems, I implement it like this:

- the real function sits in lib.universal , and expects args like 'dbSession'
- if needed, I'd also make a wrapper function that sits in lib.pyramid , and just wraps the universal -- passing in the relevant stuff from 'request'

he's a simple, and silly , example :

lib.universal

```
from ... import model
def get_user_by_id( dbSession , id , permissionsObject ):
    if not validate_permissions( permissionsObject ):
         raise ValueError('Not allowed')
    return dbSession.query( model.User ).filter( id=id ).first()
```

lib.pyramid

```
from .. import universal
def get_user_by_id( request , id ):
    return universal.get_user_by_id( request.dbSession , id , request.permissionsObject     )
```

Comment: I get what you mean about the wrapper. Currently, I have wrappers for most Pyramid specific functions such as in the pyramid_mailer package (see comment I left on Michaels answer) so that my api remains decoupled from Pyramid. I'm wondering if there is a more technical reason as to why I should avoid doing this in favor of passing the request around.